# Reading in file and using Strtok, some fields read successfully, some fields do not

Tags: c, file, parsing, io, strtok

I'm making a function to read in data from a file. The file input is a name and and ID#.

Example: 
"George Washington, 2345678
John Adams, 3456789
Thomas Jefferson, 4567890"

I can read in all the names correctly, but the id numbers do not read correctly. The numbers that are read in are all right around 2682824. None of the ID's are close to that. Sometimes the numbers go up or down by 5 but stay around those numbers. Here is the code I have now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void readDataIn(){
struct pres tempFill[30];
char s[2] = ",";
char t[50], j[1900];
char *token, *token2;
int *h;
int i = 0, f;
    FILE* file;



    if((file=fopen("AssignmentOneInput.txt", "r")) != NULL){
    while(fgets(j, sizeof(j), file)){
    token = strtok(j, ",");
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    printf(" %i\n", token);

    }


    pause;

    }
pause;
fclose(file);
return;


}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28401475/3185968 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `strtok` second time in the `while` loop, pass `NULL` as the argument instead of `j`.

```
token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

When you pass `NULL` in the first argument, `strtok` resumes parsing from the last token. When you pass `j`, it parses starting from `j` again.

Please check out [`strtok` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok).

The other problem is that you are using

```
printf(" %i\n", token);
```

`token` is still a string. `"%i"` is not the right format specifier to use here. You need to use:

```
printf(" %s\n", token);
```

Comment: Edited the code, unfortunately it didn't make a difference.